# Как отсортировать многоуровневый массив? - Регистронезависимая сортировка для кириллицы?

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отфильтровать многоуровневый массив по значению вложенного массива 'name' без учета регистра.

Сортировка должна происходить от наиболее полного совпадения (СТРОКА === СТРОКА). Количество вхождений неважно. Главное чтобы было хотя бы одно. Массивы с найденной подстрокой в 'name' сортируются по возрастанию количества символов. Строки без вхождения подстроки должны быть в самом конце массива.

```
<?php 
$substr = 'СТРОКА';
$arrayName = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Текст текст СТРОКА текст текст'),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'СТРОКА'),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'текст текст'),
        array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'текстСТРОКАтекст'),
    );

// Результат должен быть такой:
// 1. 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'СТРОКА'
// 2. 'id' => 4, 'name' => 'текстСТРОКАтекст'
// 3. 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Текст текст СТРОКА текст текст'
// 4. 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'текст текст'

$arrayName = array(
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'СТРОКА'),
        array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'текстСТРОКАтекст'),
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Текст текст СТРОКА текст текст'),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'текст текст'),
    );
 ?>
```

Comment: а вы как то сформулировать словами критерий можете? например, по возрастанию кол-ва символов, кроме СТРОКА?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Сортировка должна происходить от наиболее полного совпадения (СТРОКА === СТРОКА). Количество вхождений неважно. Главное чтобы было хотя бы одно. Строки без вхождения подстроки должны быть в самом конце массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общая схема:
1. Временно дополняем массив значениями параметра для сортировки.
2. Сортируем массив по этому параметру.
3. Удаляем параметр из массива.

Особенности вычисления параметра:
1. Использованы копии строк в однобайтовой кодировке CP_1251 (Windows-1251).
2. Строки сравниваются в верхнем регистре.
3. Функция cyrtoupper_1251() адаптирована под кириллицу.

```
$substr = 'строкА';
$arrayName = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Текст текст СТРОКА текст текст'),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'СТРОКА'),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'текст текст'),
        array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'текстСТРОКАтекст'),
    );

function cyrtoupper_1251($str){
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++){ 
        if(($ord = ord($str[$i]))>223) $ord-=32;
        $str[$i]= chr($ord);
    }
    return strtoupper($str);
}

print("Исходный массив: "); var_dump($arrayName);  

$sub_1251 = mb_convert_encoding($substr, 'CP1251');
$sub_upper = cyrtoupper_1251($sub_1251);
array_walk($arrayName, function(&$item) use($sub_upper) {   // дописываем параметр сортировки
    $name_1251 = cyrtoupper_1251(mb_convert_encoding($item["name"], 'CP1251'));
    $len = strpos($name_1251, $sub_upper) === FALSE ? 999 : strlen($name_1251);
    array_push($item, $len);
});

usort($arrayName, function($a,$b) use($sub1251) {   // сортируем
    return end($a)-end($b);
});

array_walk($arrayName, function(&$item) {           // удаляем
    array_pop($item);
});

print("Отсортированный массив: "); var_dump($arrayName);
```

Результаты:

```
Исходный массив:
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'Текст текст СТРОКА текст текст' (length=56)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'СТРОКА' (length=12)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 3
      'name' => string 'текст текст' (length=21)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 4
      'name' => string 'текстСТРОКАтекст' (length=32)
Отсортированный массив:
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'СТРОКА' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 4
      'name' => string 'текстСТРОКАтекст' (length=32)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'Текст текст СТРОКА текст текст' (length=56)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 3
      'name' => string 'текст текст' (length=21)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
usort($arrayName, 
      function ($a, $b) use($substr) { 
         $v = [$a['name'], $b['name']];
         foreach($v as &$i) {                                 // дадим вес строке
            if ($i === $substr) $i = 0;                       // 0 - равна subst
            elseif(!(false === strpos($i, $substr))) $i = 1;  // 1 - включает подстроку
            else $i = 2;                                      // 2 - когда подстроки нет 
            }
         return $v[0]-$v[1]; });                              // и отсортируем по этому весу
print_r($arrayName);
```

Comment: Здорово, но это регистрозависимая сортировка. Мне нужна регистронезависимая.

Comment: Т.е. если $substr будет равна 'Строка' или 'стРОКа', то сортировка не сработает.

Comment: Тогда надо немного переписать

Comment: Я не знаю как промапить $v методом mb_strtolower(array, 'UTF-8').

Comment: `foreach($array as &$str)`.... Но только и патерн надо так же